# Choosing the right tool for desktop application

Tags: web-applications, desktop-application, desktop

I've done a few search's and came up with some good info but one thing people usually ask is what am i trying to do, well that part i couldn't read up on:

What I'm trying to do is make a application for mainly windows but will be used on macs, the application will be launched from your computer and it will get its info from a server..like an iPhone or Android app, but from your desktop.

The application will be for doing a drop down search for a product which then pops up with all its uses. I would like to incorporate a search tool as well.

My education is making flash and building sites using Dreamweaver:)

Comment: This would be a fairly simple web application with a javascript front end issuing ajax queries to a server. The server would offer up web services probably using JSON. It would run in various browsers and on various computers without much extra work.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways of doing this, I would either do java or python. You could have them pull data from online so they sync up. I did something like this from python that pulled data from google spreadsheets. There are compilers for python that will make executables for you such as exe's and dmgs(?)

Comment: Not to make this sound like i'm lazy but would Python be the easiest to learn and execute ? and can i expand on this professionally with not worrying that Python will be extinct like Adobe Air :)

Comment: In my opinion Python is easier to learn only because its almost English. Java would be easy because it is more known and there are millions of examples and tutorials available.